# Amazon EC2 instance public acces on website from IIS server fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, webserver, host

I can't seem to access my server from the local ipv4 my instance shows in Amazon. When I try to access the website it fails also I couldn't ping to it.

Does anyone know how to fix this or help me if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common asked question which I've read a lot on the internet but couldn't find a clear answer. The problem is that your server instance doesn't allow all traffic which is connecting to your server. You have to open all gates for your server. To do so, login into your account on Amazon. When logged in go to your server instance. Then on your EC2 dashboard scroll down and click on 'Security groups'. After clicking on 'Security groups' from the dashboard click on your last created security group, you can see this from the description of your last created instance. Then select your instance and choose >> 'inbound'. [Click to see where you have to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9qXs.png). After clicking on the button 'Edit', add a new line under your RDP connection. The new line has to look like this >> 
[Click this to see how the line has to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nY1d.png) your connection has to allow all traffic as you can notice.